# updating row correctly using PHP

Tags: php, forms, csv

I'm trying to use a html form and PHP to update entries in a .csv file, but for someone reason it only works for the first entry.

if I try to write to another line it just writes to line second line (first entry.

This is the PHP

```
    <?php
$msg= ' Information Updated';

if (isset($_POST['rows'])) {

    $fp = fopen('./contact.csv', 'r+');
    foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    rewind($fp);
    $csv = '';
    while (($row = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
            $csv .= $row;
        }
    fclose($fp);

    echo $csv;
    echo $msg;
    exit;

}

?>
```

This is the HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <hr/>
    <input type="hidden" type="text" value="id" name="rows[0][]" />
    <input type="text" value="firstname" name="rows[0][]"/>
    <input type="text" value="lastname" name="rows[0][]"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It's meant to write each input to the line shown in row but it doesn't work. I have a large .CSV about 600 lines and unless I write every line in-between it always writes to the row 0 or 1

what have I done wrong?

Comment: Hi there, please, [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then came back with some code.

Comment: Done but I was really after ideas rather than someone telling me what's wrong with the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

In html it will be quite enough to flatten the array

```
<form method="post">
    <hr/>
    <input type="hidden" type="text" value="id" name="rows[]" />
    <input type="text" value="firstname" name="rows[]"/>
    <input type="text" value="lastname" name="rows[]"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In PHP there are no need to

- open file with r+ param(that moves pointer to the start),
- rewind file pointer to the end of file
- add line in csv
- and then do hardly understandable stuff

just

```
<?php
$msg = ' Information Updated';

if ( isset( $_POST['rows'] ) ) {
    $fp = fopen( './contact.csv', 'a+' );
    fputcsv( $fp, array_values( $_POST['rows'] ) );
    fclose( $fp );
    echo $msg;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Trouble with that is it won’t replace/override the values on a certain line in the .CSV it just adds it at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood the task :)

Comment: Its okay, could I use something like f(seek) to move between lines in the .CSV?